# How do I broadcast the lowest word of a __m256i?

Tags: intrinsics, avx2

I am trying to write AVX2 code using intrinsics.  Want to know how to use Intel intrinsics to broadcast the lowest word in an YMM to an entire YMM.  I know that with assembly code I could just write

```
vpbroadcastw ymm1, xmm0
```

because the lowest word of ymm0 is also the lowest word of xmm0.  I have a variable x which is a value in an YMM.  But

```
_mm256_broadcastw_epi16((__m128i) x)
```

where x is an __m256i returns an error -- can't convert two things of different sizes.

`rq_recip3_new.c:381:5: error: can’t convert a value of type ‘__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}’ to vector type ‘__vector(2) long long int’ which has different size`

I don't think this matters but my machines use gcc 6.4.1 and 7.3 (Fedora 25 and Ubuntu LTS 16.04 respectively).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```c
__m256i broadcast_word(__m256i x){
    return _mm256_broadcastw_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(x));
}
```

With intrinsics, `_mm256_castsi256_si128` is the right way to cast from 256 to 128 bits.

With [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) this compiles to (gcc 7.3):

```
broadcast_word:
  vpbroadcastw ymm0, xmm0
ret
```

Comment: @Bo-YinYang: Great! Feel free to upvote the answer. :)